# Locked out of BIOS on ASUS T100TAM

Tags: boot, bios, passwords

I am locked out of my ASUS T100TAM BIOS. I can't even boot to windows. It only pulls up the blue BIOS password screen. Now, I have learned through research that I can enter a "rescue password" to reset it. I also have learned that I can generate a "rescue password" through bios-pw.org. However, in order to generate a password through bios-pw, I have to have a code. I don't know what code to put in in order to get the correct rescue password. Any help?

Answer (score 1):

If you are locked out of your BIOS and you don't know the password, you might want to try removing the BIOS battery, waiting for a couple of seconds, then placing in back in (which should cause the BIOS to reset). [This](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=swjFc-3Z04c) should be able to help you.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for your help! I have no way to get into the BIOS battery because this is a transformer. It's a 2in1, tablet with connecting keyboard using a docking station.

Comment: @JessicaMunn Hmm. I guess then you will have to go with your original method, unless you can figure out how to open your computer. Does your BIOS give an error message when you boot up?

Comment: Unfortunately not. It simply asks for the nonexistent password.

Comment: Oh. Then you might want to call Asus and ask them why this is happening, or you can try and follow [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IBo8QwfmYSM).

Answer (score 0):

The code you are searching for should come up after you enter the BIOS password wrong multiple times, and then the code will come up on the screen. Once you have that code, you may go to the recovery site you listed and enter it there.